# Banner image will not display correct size

Tags: html, css, image-size

My banner images are not displaying correctly. I have a scrolling banner in my index.html doc with three rotating pictures. I have tried to pre-size the 3 pictures to a standardized 1920px x 800px. Only one of the pictures seems to display correctly. The other 2 leave room on the right side and 1 also is not displaying correctly at the bottom. As you can see, I even have line item attributes to control the width (`data-image-width='1920'`)and height (`data-image-height='800'`).
[image]

When you mouse over the image it gives the size as 1440 × 600 pixels (Natural: 1920 × 800 pixels) on all three. I also have css in my styles.css file to control the main-baner class under which the images reside.

```
.main-baner {position: relative; float: left; width: 100%; margin-top: 50px; height: 600px;}
.main-baner img {width: 100%; height: auto;}
```

Any idea as to why the images are not displaying as a standard size?

Comment: Your code **should** handle your images correctly, but in order for us to work out exactly what is causing the problem, please update your question so that it shows all relevant code in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please refer to the [help article](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) regarding how to ask good questions.

Comment: Save yourself the hassle and turn the `img` element into a `div` with `background-image:url(insert url); background-size:cover`. The image will fill as big as it can without squishing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.center_img{`
    `width: 100%;`
  
}

use 100% in your image class.

Comment: That got it. I had an inline `style='width: 100%" in the div for the bad image, but it wasn't applied to the `center_img` class itself. Thanks.